# Porting Firefox OS to Android device

Tags: android, porting, firefox-os, b2g

I would like to port Firefox OS to my device (that is not supported by Mozilla but it has Android 4.2). I've read from net that some of the drivers haven't been developed yet, but if FFOS uses the kernel from Android, then it can load the drivers from my Android ROM, right?

From this point, my real question is: if I build my FFOS ROM correctly, would I still have some bugs from hardware/drivers?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Leakspin, I'll try to give you some context on whether it's doable, and what has been done yet.

**if FFOS uses the kernel from Android, then it can load the drivers from my Android ROM, right?**

- Yes and No. There is much more than that. As you can see, Firefox is built putting together several pieces, such as Gonk(what you were referring to "android kernel", Gecko (our application runtime), and finally Gaia (user interface). Take a look at the Stack. For more info, please follow the [architecture blog post at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Platform/Architecture).

  [image: Firefox OS architecture]

**Has it been ported yet to any Android devices?**

- Yes, but it's not a simple process and there is no guarantee that it will work on all android devices. Here, have a look at the list of devices and which tools you will need to perform such operation.

There is also a porting tutorial you might want to follow.

**f I build my FFOS ROM correctly, would I still have some bugs from hardware/drivers?**

- Unfortunately, very likely that you will do.

I tried my best to style this answer, but the stupid stackoverflow limited the amount of links and images I'm able to post. Sorry for that.

Links:

[How to port Firefox OS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Porting)

[Pre-requisites](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Firefox_OS_build_prerequisites#Have_a_compatible_device_or_use_an_emulator).

Comment: Okey, I think you pretty much explain what others didn't! Thank you! Even though, I think I have to postpose my porting - the manufacturer hasn't released all source code yet... Thank you again :)

Comment: I would recommend you to wait a little, as Mozilla's contracts with manufacturers/service providers, obligates them to provide Firefox OS updates every 6 months. Soon, Firefox OS will be in version 1.3, but the stable version is still 1.2. You're more than welcome.