# Port B2G to a specific device

Tags: firefox-os, b2g

In the [Firefox OS documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Preparing_for_your_first_B2G_build#Configuring_B2G_for_your_device), one can read :

> If your device isn't listed, you should stop right now and either help port B2G to your device or wait until someone else does it. We'd prefer it if you help out!

How should I help to port B2G to my device (Alcatel Orange Klif / OneTouch 4022D) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MDN has a full guide for beginning a new port of Firefox OS to a specific device:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Developing_Firefox_OS/Porting

There's a similar question here:

[Porting Firefox OS to Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647465/porting-firefox-os-to-android-device?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, you do need some basic background like:
* git
* Some C/C++ programming knowledge
* How Android build system works
* Be consistent
* Be patient

You are ok with that, right? :)

So let's start reading:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Developing_Firefox_OS/Porting
Any doubts? Pretty sure. Come to irc.mozilla.org #b2g and introduce yourself, there's a lot of passionate and lovely people there willing to help newcomers contributors who really want to make their projects real.